# How to override default form checkout summary step in CoreShop

Tags: symfony4, pimcore, coreshop

I have a default implementation of the summary checkout step.
It is located in file vendor/coreshop/core-shop/src/CoreShop/Bundle/CoreBundle/Form/Type/Checkout/SummaryType.php
I need to add a custom code to SummaryType::buildForm method.

How can I do it correctly?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In app/config/services.yml add lines:

```
AppBundle\Form\Type\SummaryType:
    arguments:
        - '%coreshop.model.cart.class%'
        - '%coreshop.form.type.checkout.summary.validation_groups%'
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }

coreshop.checkout.step.summary: '@AppBundle\CoreBundle\Checkout\Step\SummaryCheckoutStep'
AppBundle\CoreBundle\Checkout\Step\SummaryCheckoutStep:
    arguments:
        - '@form.factory'
```

Also, add src/AppBundle/Form/Type/SummaryType.php class file:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;


use CoreShop\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Form\Type\AbstractResourceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;


class SummaryType extends AbstractResourceType
{


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('acceptTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
                'constraints' => [new NotBlank(['groups' => $this->validationGroups])],
                'label' => 'coreshop.ui.accept_terms',
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
            ->add('comment', TextareaType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'coreshop.ui.comment',
            ]);
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'coreshop_checkout_summary';
    }
}
```